# How can the `notify_url` guarantee the request is the 3tr payment?

Tags: paypal, payment

How can the `notify_url` guarantee the request is the 3tr payment ?

We know in a Payment such as use PayPal, if the PayPal payment success, it will request the `notify_url` we given, but the notify_url we implement in the backend.

But I have a question, how can we ensure the request user is the 3tr payment(such as PayPal), not a simulated user cracker?

Comment: You implement the check-notify procedure described in the documentation. Off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to PayPal and/or is already answered by PayPal documentation.